# find multiple text in one expression

Tags: .net, blueprism

I started learning Reg Ex yesterday as I use the automation software Blue Prism and you can write Reg Ex's.

I need to pull the same data each time (example shown below) and that is the persons KID (in this case `J16203`), their Payroll number (`6554739`) and their Contract end date (22/02/14)

I've written `/KID ([A-Za-z]){1}\d{4,5}` to pull out their KID (which always begins with a letter and then is 4 or 5 digits). How do I add to this to pull out their payroll number and contract end date?

```
Persons data
This is their KID J16203
Person’s Payroll number 6554739
Contract end date 22/02/14
```

Comment: Have you provided your *actual* regular expression? You'll need a named capture group in order to extract anything using the .NET engine and Blue Prism, and I don't see one in the pattern you've provided.

Comment: You're also more likely to get a quality answer if you show what you've tried and what hasn't worked.

Answer (score 0):

In this way, you can fetch both KID and Payroll number using one RegExr expression.

`/(KID [^a-b]{5,6}|number [0-9]{7})`

Anyway, you can always write RegExr expression online by using: https://regexr.com/